# Changing internal default values of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, configuration

I would like to know,

1) how the settings for parameters that are not specified (or commented out) in the current rcParams file come about.

2) How to change those, not touching the rcParams file.

Background:
I have a local rcParams file, which I want to use on different machines with the same scripts in order to make the plots look similar. Same rcParams, same scripts, different machines.
On one machine I need to use backend A, on the other I need to use backend B (there is no choice.) 
I have commented out the line where the backend is specified in the rcParams file. 
Thus, a default backend is loaded by matplotlib. I would like to specify in some location on each machine, what this default backend is, so that on one machine, backend A is loaded automatically and backend B on the other.
Using different scripts or different rcParams files oneach machine is also not an option.

Comment: you can [dynamically set rcParams settings](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#dynamic-rc-settings)

Comment: I think you want the `style` module http://matplotlib.org/api/style_api.html

Comment: @tcaswell: I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @tom: I know, but this is not feasible in my case, because I want to use the same scripts (from an svn repository) on both machines. Thus I would like to avoid lines in the script that check on which machine the script is running which would be necessary to make machine specific settings.